# Scale only one axis in Altair with interactive plot

Tags: python, altair

I am using Altair 4.1.0 to create interactive plots with Python. I want to be able to zoom in some part of my chart by scaling only one axis, for example only the y-axis while keeping the x-axis fixed. From the documentation I could not find a way to do this. My understanding is that `alt.interactive()` corresponds to `.add_selection(alt.selection_interval(bind='scales'))`, but still I don't see how to achieve my purpose. Is there any way to do this in Altair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`alt.Chart.interactive`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html?highlight=interactive#altair.Chart.interactive) has `bind_x` and `bind_y` arguments which default to `True`. If you set either of these to `False`, that scale will not be part of the interaction:

```python
chart.interactive(bind_x=False)
```

Alternatively, you can do this manually by specifying the encodings you want bound (`['x']`, `['y']`, or `['x', 'y']`, which is the default):

```python
chart.add_selection(alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', encodings=['y']))
```